# InvalidCastException from C# back-end

Tags: c#, sql, datetimeoffset

I'm receiving different behavior form local environment to development environment due to Invalid casting of DateTimeOffset related issues. Strangely enough the same web application is also in test environment and is working without error.  The only place I'm receiving the error is in development, but no in test or in my local computer.

Error I'm receiving:

```
 [InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_DateTime() +6531011
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetDateTime(Int32 i) +61
   G_C.G_C_CodeGroupData.ReadDBRowForMaint() +765
   G_C.G_C_CodeGroupEdit.OnInit(EventArgs e) +341
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +186
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2098
```

From C# code I'm calling a stored procedure that is retrieving data from columns this way:

```
dr.GetDateTimeOffset(4).ToLocalTime().DateTime.ToString()
```

On the other hand, the stored procedure is just a select statement selecting records based on the id.

The column definitions for that specific column is :

```
[VAR_CREATE_DATE] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_G_C_CODE_VARIABLE_VAR_CREATE_DATE]  DEFAULT (sysdatetimeoffset()),
```

There's might be a very explicit reason why I can't get rid of this error, but it is escaping me at this moment. I can't see where the error is; or what is triggering it.

PS. Local and Test environment are looking to the same database and table definitions.

Thank you,
N.

Comment: Are the Local times on the servers all the same?

Comment: same regional settings?

Comment: Unless I'm misreading things here, your call stack doesn't appear to match your code snippet. The call stack talks about the method GetDateTime, while the source code calls GetDateTimeOffset.  This makes me think you don't have the code you think you do deployed to the Development server.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing. Looking at Reference Source, GetDateTimeOffset doesn't call GetDateTime.

Comment: The website was migrated recently when this bug was reported. I looked for that call in the entire solution and I wasn't able to find it, only the ReadDBRowForMaint().  Local times on the servers are all the same...But now I'll check the web service for that application just in case...

Comment: is this magic number 4 a column index? maybe column order is not consistent across systems, a `SELECT *`?